# How to use a bit data type in OutSystems

Tags: outsystems

I am trying to work with conditional data ( true or false ) in outsystems using bits (0 or 1). All I see is an option for a boolean. Does outsystems have a bit data type?

Comment: any specific reason why you want to use a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: boolean data types are mapped into the database as 0 (false) and 1 (true). Additionally, you can use integers to do that logic, but I would advise against it.

Cheers!

Comment: "Long answer: boolean data types are mapped into the database as 0 (false) and 1 (true). " - The boolean gets translated to a bit field in SQL server.

Just to clear up any confusion.